# Error after installation of Qgis 2.12

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-2.12

I install Qgis 2.12 but after installation I try to open Qgis and I resive this  three errors. 
*"The program Can't start because qgis_xxx.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the programm to fix this problem"*
I reinstall Qgis but nothing cahange and the same errors.

[image]

Comment: Does it still crash if you run the **qgis.bat** file?

Comment: No, with .bat file open without crash.

Comment: Did you install it using standalone installer or OSGeo4W Network installer?

Comment: I use:  QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.12.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: I don't have this installed so I'm only guessing, if you right-click the desktop icon _"QGIS Desktop 2.12.0"_ > Properties > Shortcut > Target_, make sure it reads something like `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\nircmd.exe exec hide C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\qgis.bat`. I only had this problem occur to me once with an earlier QGIS version and this worked for me. If not then hopefully others can advise :)

Comment: I'll try and come back for the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Most welcome buddy, atleast you can get it working using the qgis.bat file :)